# Is there a keyword for getting existing data in a record?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to update all the records in my table at once and add brackets before and after each entry in the record.
Is there anything I can add in this blank which will help me do the same?

```sql
update @column_list set ListColumns = '['+ _________ +']'
```

I have not been able to figure anything out. I thought I'd try asking here once, or else I will have to update all records separately looking at their actual values and adding brackets.

Comment: Can you show table structure, sample input and expected output?

Comment: What's your input and what is your desired output? Posting nothing but the query that *doesn't* give you what you want is rather useless.

Comment: There's no keyword to update all columns, and the main reason that there is pretty much no good reason to ever do this - different datatypes would require different rules (e.g. if you add `[` and `]` to a number or a date), it will cease to be a number of a date. This sounds very much like an [xy problem](https://xyproblem.info/). so I think a better question is **WHY** do you need to modify all columns in all rows at once, rather than how do you do it?

Comment: UPDATE   ColX = CONCAT('[', ColX, ']') FROM Something

Comment: In TSQL, DBA write cols explicitly in every statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why you'd want to encapsulate everything in brackets, but what comes to my mind is doing something like this:

```
UPDATE [tableName]
SET
    [col1] = CONCAT('[',[col1],']')
    ,[col2] = CONCAT('[',[col2],']')
    ,...
```

If you want to perform this action on insert or update to the table itself you can create a trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER [triggerName]
ON [tableName]
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF TRIGGER_NESTLEVEL()>1
        RETURN;

    UPDATE [tableName]
    SET
        [col1] = CONCAT('[', [col1], ']')
        ,[col2] = CONCAT('[', [col2], ']')
        ,....
    WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID FROM INSERTED);
END
```

However, setting type (n)varchar into another data type column will cause issues.